# How to change UINavigationBar font & color?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to change font and color of my UINavigationBar from the AppDelegate. For this I do:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    appearance.translucent = false
    appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 21)!]
    appearance.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 80/255, green: 185/255, blue: 225/255, alpha: 1)
    appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

but in this case works just one of them, for example:

if I set at first - Font, at the second - color, it just change color, not font, too. If I set at first - Color, at the second - Font, it just change font, not color, too.

How can I change both of them?

Comment: "I want to change font and color of my UINavigationController" A UINavigationController is not a view. It has no font or color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let appearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    appearance.translucent = false
    appearance.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 80/255, green: 185/255, blue: 225/255, alpha: 1)
    appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 21)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about it. You are saying:

```
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 21)!]
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

So in the second line you *throw away* the title text attributes you set in the first line. This is not additive in some magical way: you are *replacing* what you did in the first line with what you do in the second line.